# How to create partitioned table based on one Integer column (each value = 1 partition) in Oracle 12c?

Tags: sql, oracle, partition, database-partitioning

There is a non-partitioned table in Oracle 12c, call it 't1' with 10M records that has 3 columns (a,b,c).

Column 'a' has 100 distinct integer values.

How to create a second table 't2' that has all the values from 't1' but is partitioned based on column 'a' so that each partition correspond to one distinct value in column 'a'? (there should be 100 partitions created).

Thanks!

Comment: Check Oracle documentation for **Reference Partitioning**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a automatic list partition while creating table t2 and later insert records from table t1 which will create a new partition for each distinct value in the mentioned column 'a'.

Note : While creating automatic list partition you need to specify atleast one partition.

eg :- 
CREATE TABLE t2 (
a number,b varchar2(200),c varchar2(200)
)
PARTITION BY LIST (a) AUTOMATIC (
   PARTITION P_10 VALUES (10)
);

insert into t2 select * from t1;

This insert will create partitions automatically for each distinct value.

Comment: What is `VALUES (10) ` part doing?

Comment: As i have already mentioned we need atleast one partition with the list partioning hence, PARTITION P_10 VALUES (10) creates one partition with a value 10 for column a in your case. 10 is just a dummy value used ony for example. You can have any one dsitinct value of column a instead of 10.

Comment: Ok, and that value '10' or whatever I put as example - need to be existing currently in the column, correct?

Comment: its not necessary that 10 needs to be existing in the column. But if it is existing in the column then when we insert that record with value 10 in the table t2, it will show one record under partition P_10 else if there is no record in t1 with value 10 then there won't be any records under partitiion P_10.

Comment: Glad to know that :)